# How to atomically load fresh & update an existing Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, concurrency, transactions

In my code, I have an existing Eloquent model. I want to atomically:

- load a fresh copy of it from the DB, and
- if its state is as expected, update one column.

I wrote the following code:

```
private function getRefreshedAndUpdated(MyEloquentModel $old_model)
{
    $id = $old_model->id;
    $new_model = null;
    DB::transaction(function () use ($id, &$new_model) {
        $new_model = MyEloquentModel::lockForUpdate()->find($id);
        if ($new_model->state !== 'READY') {
            throw new \Exception('Model not ready');
        }
        $new_model->state = 'UPDATED';
        $new_model->save();
    });
    return $new_model;
}
```

**Does this accomplish what I want?**

In particular, am I guaranteed that `MyEloquentModel::lockForUpdate()->find($id)`:

- will always fetch the model fresh from DB (skipping any cache perhaps seeded by fetching `$old_model` before)?
- will lock it preventing any changes e.g. via `$old_model` (via pthreads) or the underlying DB record in another process?

I suspect it will, but this is for some critical code, so want to double check.

Comment: there are the `fresh` and `refresh` methods on Model, btw

Comment: You can use the [cache to create atomic locks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#managing-locks), as well.

Comment: @lagbox Thanks very much, I was aware of their existence. However, I don't know if they offer the guarantees I'm looking for here. Do you know?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Thank you. I'm looking for something more fundamental though - at the DB level.